# Random Empty space in my html page layout

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table of clickable logos within my body table on my website and for some reason there is a blank space before the table is shown. It may just be a problem with my code but here is the page in question. (Includes were used, but I pasted them all together to make it clearer)

Can anyone see what is causing this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
    <body id="page" style="background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;" background="pictures/shopshelves.JPG">

        <table align="center">
            <div id="header">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" width="950" height="150"></h1></td>
            </tr>
            </div>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" width="950" height="217">
                <div style='position:center'><img src='pictures/logo.bmp'></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <div id="navigation">
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/index.php">Home</a>
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/LoginPage.php">Members</a>
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/lists.php">My Lists</a>
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/offers.php">Current Special Offers</a>
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/clubcards.php">My Clubcards</a>
                    <a href="http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/ShoppingHelper/popular.php">My Popular Items</a>
            </div>
            <table  align="center" border= "5px">
            <td width="950 bgcolor="white" align="center">
            <div id="content">


            <b>Here are some links to the special offers in some of the major supermarkets near you:</b/><br/><br/>
        <table >
                <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.tesco.ie/groceries/SpecialOffers/default.aspx" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/tesco.png"></a></td> <br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.dunnesstores.ie/groceryleaflet/" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/dunnes.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://supervalu.ie/offers/all-offers/" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/supervalu.png"></a></td><br><p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.aldi.ie/ie/html/offers/special_buys.htm?WT.z_src=main" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/aldi.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.lidl.ie/cps/rde/xchg/lidl_ri_ie/hs.xsl/special-offers.htm" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/lidl.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://viewer.zmags.com/publication/2bc4f269#/2bc4f269/1" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/centra.png"></a></td><br><p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.londis.ie/community/instore/special" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/londis.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.spar.ie/promotions.html" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/spar.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.gala.ie/template1.php?page=promotions" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/gala.png"></a></td><br><p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://content.yudu.com/A23mte/SQF5A2013/resources/index.htm?referrerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.superquinn.ie%2Faspx%2FContent.aspx%3Fid%3D866" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/superquinn.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.mace.ie/special-offers/special-offers" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/mace.png"></a></td><br><p>
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.costcutter.ie/index.php/special-offers/" target="_blank"><img src="pictures/costcutter.png"></a></td><br><br><br><br>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" width="950" height="150" style="filter: alpha(opacity=50)" align="center"><h4>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="pictures/facebook.jpg"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="pictures/Twitter.jpg"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://plus.google.com"><img src="pictures/Google+.jpg"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have 2 body tags - the second one has no closing `>`

Comment: What's this line doing in there: `<body style="background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;" background="pictures/shopshelves.JPG"` ?

Comment: Also keep in mind that using tables to create layouts is considered bad practice. Please read into divs if you haven't already.

Comment: I have edited it there with a copy of the inspected element, does anyone know how to solve this?
@kenneth it is a background for the whole page that does not scroll when the page does, its just a big picture

Comment: Well, you can't have two body tags as mentioned in various replies. Please remove one of the body-tags and check again if that solves your problem.

Comment: Solved! Before i made these links into a table i was using line breaks and paragraph breaks to separate the links, and i failed to remove them when i put them into a table!
Working perfect now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have two opening body tags.  I also see a few other unclosed tags (ie the unopened  in your first table row).  Get your html valid and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td width="950 bgcolor="white" align="center">
```

You are also missing a quote here after 950.